# How add a background image on a QWidget and add positional QLineedit on top of it?

Tags: python, image, background, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to set a background image on a QWidget and have some QlineEdit on top of it.

So for know I have this code

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
class Model_GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent= None ):
        super(Model_GUI, self).__init__()

        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 800
        self.height = 800
        self.resize(self.width,self.height)

        GB = QGroupBox(" Gain ")
        GB_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        label = QLabel('A')
        edit  = QLineEdit('1')
        GB_layout.addWidget(label)
        GB_layout.addWidget(edit)
        GB.setLayout(GB_layout)

        GB2 = QGroupBox(" Gain ")
        GB_layout2 = QHBoxLayout()
        label2 = QLabel('A')
        edit2 = QLineEdit('1')
        GB_layout2.addWidget(label2)
        GB_layout2.addWidget(edit2)
        GB2.setLayout(GB_layout2)

        #Graph
        Graph = graph()

        self.CentralWidget = QWidget()
        self.globallayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.globallayout.addWidget(GB)
        self.globallayout.addWidget(Graph)
        self.globallayout.addWidget(GB2)

        self.CentralWidget.setLayout(self.globallayout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CentralWidget)


class graph(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(600,600)

        oImage = QImage("img.png")
        sImage = oImage.scaled(QSize(self.width(), self.height()))  # resize Image to widgets size
        palette = QPalette()
        palette.setBrush(10, QBrush(sImage))  # 10 = Windowrole
        self.setPalette(palette)

        self.label1 = QLabel('Param1', self)
        self.edit1 = QLineEdit('1', self)
        self.label2 = QLabel('Param2', self)
        self.edit2 = QLineEdit('10', self)
        self.label1.move(50, 50)
        self.edit1.move(500, 50)
        self.label2.move(50, 500)
        self.edit2.move(500, 500)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Model_GUI(app)
    ex.setWindowTitle('window')
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_( ))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but when I execute it I don't have the image in the QWidget (in the middle).

[image]

If I replace `ex = Model_GUI(app)`with `ex = graph()`, I have the correct expectation :

[image]

I don't understand why the image is correctly set when I'm using the QWidget alone but it isn't set right when I embedded it in a QMainWindow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QWidgets use their `QPalette.Window` role only if they are top level widgets (as in "windows"), otherwise the parent background is used instead unless the [`autoFillBackground`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#autoFillBackground-prop) property (which is false by default) is true.

Just set the property in the widget initialization:

```
self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```